# How can I find the function in PostgreSQL that is workable but doesn't exist in the schemas?

Tags: database, postgresql, oracle

I just took over a PostgreSQL database (version: PostgreSQL 11.11 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.0, 64-bit), that database was migrated from an Oracle database. In that database, I can run some Oracle-specific functions (not built-in functions in PostgreSQL) and get the correct result without any errors, like:

```
select nvl(null, 1);
select decode(1, 1, 'true', 0, 'false');
```

But I can't find these functions even though I exported entire schemas, none of following script:

```
select pg_get_functiondef(oid)
from pg_proc
where lower(proname) like '%nvl%';
```

And there are no any related extensions like orafce installed in this database.
How can I find the definition of these functions?
[image: function nvl()]
[image: function decode]
[image: can not find the function]
[image: no extensions]

Comment: These are built-in functions their definition exist in the source code and not in the database

Comment: @Aurangzeb I think these functions are not built-in in PostgreSQL database.

Comment: @Aurangzeb: those aren't built-in for Postgres. But even the built-in functions in Postgres **do** show up in `pg_proc`  "in the database".

Comment: these are functions but they're also termed as keywords, they're not listed

Answer (score -1):

From the column names in the outputs, it appears that `NVL` and `DECODE` are being translated into `COALESCE` and `CASE`, respectively. Somewhere these translations must be defined. If no extensions have been added, and no functions have these names, then it's possible that the source from which the PostgreSQL executables were created was modified to perform these translations.

`COALESCE` is the standard SQL equivalent to Oracle's `NVL` (Oracle supports both).

There isn't a direct equivalent to `DECODE` in PostgreSQL; however, it can be translated to `CASE` expressions. Keep in mind that Oracle's `DECODE` considers two NULLs to be equivent. An equivalent to

```
DECODE(search_value, NULL, 'unknown', 0, 'false', 1, 'true', 'invalid');
```

is

```
CASE search_value
  WHEN 0 THEN 'false'
  WHEN 1 THEN 'true'
  ELSE
    CASE
      WHEN search_value IS NULL THEN 'unknown'
      ELSE 'invalid'
    END
END
```

Comment: How does this answer question "Why `nvl` works in my Postgre"?